# Grant permission for the path

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, windows-10

I am following this [guide](https://gorails.com/setup/windows/10), to install ruby, while everything has no problem except when I try to run this command

**rails new myapp -d mysql**

in which I got this error

```
  run  bundle install
There was an error while trying to write to
`/home/fil/.bundle/cache/compact_index/rubygems.org.443.29b0360b937aa4d161703e6160654e47`. It is likely that you need to
grant write permissions for that path.
         run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
bundler: command not found: spring
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
```

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Are you on Linux or Windows10?

Comment: try sudo bundle install

Comment: linux as sub system of windows 10

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like you ran `bundle install` as root at some point (via `sudo bundle install`), which you should never do. You can `sudo` it again to get past this problem, as @GurmukhSingh suggests, but that's just going to compound the problem and isn't a good idea from a security standpoint.

If you want to find files in your Bundler cache that aren't owned by `fil` (assuming your username is `fil`), you can run this:

```
find ~/.bundle/cache ! -user fil -ls
```

If that returns anything at all, then the problem is likely that those files are owned by `root` (or some other user); the `-ls` flag to `find` will show you who owns them.

You can delete the offending files and run `bundle install` again, or you can change the ownership of them with:

```
chown -R fil ~/.bundle/cache
```

You may need to check on all files in `~/.bundle` and not just the `cache` dir.

In the future, don't run `bundle install` via `sudo`.

Comment: It return this find: ``/home/fil/.bundle/cache': No such file or directory`

Comment: Maybe you did `sudo bundle` the first time you used it, and `~/.bundle` is owned by root. If `ls -l ~/.bundle` shows it's owned by root, do `chmod -R fil ~/.bundle`. If you don't even have a `.bundle` directory then you've got bigger problems, like perhaps not owning your home directory.

Comment: I also try this since there's no cache and this was the result `chown -R fil ~/.bundle
chown: changing ownership of ‘/home/fil/.bundle’: Operation not permitted`

Comment: What is `ls -l /home/fil` showing? Is your filesystem mounted read-only or something crazy like that?

Comment: It just said No such file or directory

Comment: I'm tapping out. Your problem seems to be well beyond the scope of your question.

Answer (score 1):

you would have most probably run `sudo bundle install` previously.

To mitigate the issue you can try either to change the permission using

```sh
sudo chmod -R u+rw ~/.bundle
```

or, if this doesn't work, by removing the bundle and installing it again.

1. `sudo rm -rf /home/user-name/.bundle`
2. then execute `bundle` command inside your project folder