# undefined method `stubs_for' for Gem::Specification:Class (NoMethodError) Did you mean? stubs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hello I'm learning by book Ruby on Rails Tutorial. According on Tutorial I tried to install Gemfile from [Tutorial](https://github.com/mhartl/rails_tutorial_6th_edition_gemfiles/tree/master/sample_app), but I faced up some problems when I try to run

> bundle install

1. First problem is

`It is likely that you need to grant write permissions for that path.`

Then I solved it by this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40767451/grant-permission-for-the-path)

2. Second problem was

> Could not find sassc-2.4.0 in any of the sources

```
  `Building native extensions. This could take a while...ERROR: Error installing sassc:ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/sassc-2.4.0/ext/usr/bin/ruby2.5`
```

3. Now I have

   3: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.2.12/lib/bundler/source/metadata.rb:7:in `specs' 2: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.2.12/lib/bundler/index.rb:9:in` build'
   1: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.2.12/lib/bundler/source/metadata.rb:28:in `block in specs' /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.2.12/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:588:in` find_name': undefined method `stubs_for' for Gem::Spec

My OS - Linux mint 19.1
Ruby v - 2.5.1
Rails v - 6.1.3

Comment: For what it's worth, I copied your `Gemfile` and it installed without issues. It sounds to me like you've got a dodgy ruby installation, possibly because the tutorial you ran something as `sudo` and then tried to fix permissions retrospectively??

Comment: I can see other people have encountered [that exact error before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63544817/undefined-method-stubs-for-for-gemspecificationclass-nomethoderror), so you could try their solution. Or, it might be easier to just uninstall `ruby` and start again without running anything dodgy with `chmod` or `sudo`?

Comment: I have tried all this solutions, but I think you are right. It is easier to just uninstall and start it again

Comment: I'd recommend to install and or use a ruby version manager, rvm or rbenv are good start points. `rbenv` is my personal choice. Installing development gems with sudo (system-wide) is not a very good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several possible issues:

1. you may have used `bundler` as root in which case the file ownerhip expected by bundler will be incorrect.
2. your version of `gem` is probably out of date, and you have not run `gem update -system` to update it.

You may also be missing the `ruby-dev` package.  This contains the c/c++ headers requied to compile some native gem extensions.  You may also need other libraries such as libstdc++ etc.

Comment: I have updated gem and Installed ruby-dev. My problems are still here. Is it a good idea to reinstall all packages? I think I've made a mistake when used  `bundler` with **sudo** and used this code `chown -R fil ~/.bundle/cache`

Comment: It's probably best to start over, yes.  Install ruby as root on the system, but install bundler etc as the user you are intending to run the application as.